# MS Access - run an update query to replace all values based on a textbox value

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, textbox

I have a long text field where I want to add html tags to bold certain words. I am able to do this from the query builder, but because novice Access users will be using this database, I want to allow for them to enter something in a textbox to be able to do it.

My textbox is called "keywords" and my table is "final_tia_data."

```
    Private Sub Toggle7_Click()

    addboxsql = "UPDATE final_tiu_data.newreporttext, 
    Replace([gender],me.keywords,'<b>'&me.keywords&'</b>') FROM 
    final_tiu_data;"

    DoCmd.RunSQL addboxsql

    End Sub
```

I appreciate any help with this.  Thanks!

Comment: You are missing `Option Explicit` (unless you really meant to call your variable by two different names)   Also, when posting code, it's useful to describe the actual problem you see when you run it.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your current code -

Firstly, the obvious issue is the typo where you define a variable `addboxsql` and then proceed to use the variable `addboldsql` when attempting to execute the SQL.

Instead, you should declare the variables that you intend to define using `Dim` statements, and ensure that `Option Explicit` is included within your VBA module to prevent the use of undeclared variables.

The main issues relate the SQL statement itself -

In MS Access an [`UPDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/update-statement-microsoft-access-sql) query has the format:

```
UPDATE table SET newvalue WHERE criteria;
```

And you will **not** be able to use the VBA `Me` keyword within the SQL code, as it has no meaning in this context.

A quick fix might be -

```vb
Private Sub Toggle7_Click()
    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "update final_tiu_data set newreporttext = replace([gender], """ & Me.keywords & """, ""<b>" & Me.keywords & "</b>"")"
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
End Sub
```

However, this approach is still susceptible to SQL injection, and so you might consider parameterising your query or referencing the form controls using a saved query.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing Option Explicit (unless you really meant to call your variable by two different names)